# Access DTS Variable outside Main() in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, script-task

I have a variable assigned in my SSIS task. I want to access that variable inside a public static DataSet getDataSet() method in my Scriptmain.cs.

basically the variable has a connection string for my sql server and i need to get some values from a table and need to send those values as email in my script task.

[Send a table in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811353/send-a-table-in-email)

I tried to access it from the method public static Dataset however the keyword Dts is not recognized. I tried to find solution from the below link however the example states using the variable outside scriptmain and not inside a different method in script main

[Use SSIS Variable in another class besides ScriptMain.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779715/use-ssis-variable-in-another-class-besides-scriptmain-cs)

Can some one help me to access the dts variable inside a meathod inside scriptmain?

Comment: Having not seen the code I would assume you should be able to assign the dts variable to a string variable in the main and pass it into the method the same way you would any other variable.

Comment: Are you using a Script Task (Control Flow) or Script Component (Data Flow) to access your vars?  You should have access `Dts.Variables` inside of all methods of the `ScriptMain` class in a *Script Task*.  Script Component is another story...

Comment: Questions about why code isn't working should include code